# use variables when defining constants not working

Tags: php

So this is a very odd...

I am trying to define a constant to a variables content:

```
$hello='Hello World';
define('HELLO',$hello);
echo HELLO;//Outputs nothing
```

```
$hello='Hello World';
define('HELLO',"Hai There$hello");
echo HELLO;//Hai There
```

It like strips all variables... Why? And is there a way to make it work? I've searched php.net in the [define](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) function section, but i can't seem to find anything...

Comment: What version of php are you running ? you can find out by doing a phpinfo() . The above code is working for me.  Please take a look at error logs and see if there is something wrong there

Comment: please check your error logs . Do you have some informations there ? Try to put the above code in a separate file and run it there. does it work ?

Comment: Nah, it's alright. working now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
[root@mat ~]# php test.php 
Works!
[root@mat ~]# cat test.php 
<?php

$hw = 'Hello World';
define('HW', $hw);

if ( HW == "Hello World" ) {
    echo "Works!\n";
} else {
    echo "Broken!\n";
}


?>
```

You need to either test the value like above or use the constant() function.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php

This is with PHP 5. PHP 4 may behave differently.

Comment: lol let me take that back... what version of PHP are you running?

Comment: Yes you can, at least in php 5 as far as i know. Just checked the above code and it works .
 php constant.php 
Hello World
metaly@Metaly-MacBook:~/Sites$ cat constant.php
<?php

$hello='Hello World';
define('HELLO',$hello);
echo HELLO."\n";//Outputs nothing

?>

Comment: Yeah, that's why I added the comment editing post now